# Tela Branca ao carregar o app no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio, mobile

Estou usando o visual studio para a criação de um app mobile. 
Usei o comando "ionic cordova run android" para carregar no meu emulador no android studio o meu aplicativo. Aparentemente parece estar indo, mas ele só fica em tela branca.

Estou usando o jdk 8, na versão 9 ele nem aparece a tela branca, já com o 8 fica como se estivesse startando meu aplicativo, mas fica em branco a tela.

- Android Studio 3.0.1

Obs: Não apresenta erros no meu console.

Desde já, agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o meu problema, estava em tela branca assim, aí resolvi abrir via browser, dei o comando:

"ionic serve"

apresentou uns erros por não estar comentado umas linhas de código (linhas que escrevi anotação), comentei e resolveu o problema.

Usei o comando:

ionic cordova platform add android

ionic cordova run android

Aí abriu minha aplicação no emulador, tanto no  Nexus 5x e Nexus 5.

Estou com android studio 3.0.1, e o jdk 8